# Gitlab Merge Request "Re:" email prefix meaning and customization

Tags: gitlab

The Gitlab notification system sends email when a *Merge Request* is accepted and done, meaning that a branch is merged into the default branch (master, main, ...).

That notification email comes with the prefix "**Re**". But, what does that prefix mean? Is it possible to be customized by project or group preventing confusion with "Replay" or "Response"?

**Note:** All other notification emails don't come with such a prefix, but just a clean context prefix like the project name or so.

Comment: This is a common thing. Ever seen `Re:` when someone replies to your email? It's usually meant to be shorthand for _regarding_ or in _reply_ to. However, this is not really a programming question...

Comment: @sytech: programming tool behaviours are the key for software process automation, they are programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

"Re:" definition - "with reference to", or "in regards to".

[Regarding Re: ; what is the correct usage in an email subject line?](https://%20https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2520)

I believe the only way to customize this message by modifying your own deployment of the GitLab codebase.

Comment: Interesting that all other notifications emails don't have such a prefix. But "special" prefixes like the project name, or so. However, Merge Requests come with "Re:"